# DropDownList with dirtyforms jQuery plugin

Tags: forms, kendo-ui, jquery-dirtyforms

I'd like to use the jQuery plugin dirtyForms to check if my forms are dirty or not.
But it looks like the DropDownList is not based on the standard select HTML tag.
It seems instead that it's using

HTML tag.
Why this choice ? Because of that the jquery plugin dirtyForms don't set my forms dirty when I just change a DropDownList value...

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about kendo-ui or dirtyForms so I will do my best to answer this by looking at the API. The kendo-ui DropDownList has a [`change` event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#change) that looks to only get fired whenever the input in a DropDownList is changed. Additionally dirtyForms has a way of you [manually setting the form to dirty](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#public-methods). Putting the two together I would guess the following should work.

```
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    change: function(e) {
        $('form').dirtyForms('setDirty');
    }
});
```

Edit: Since you seem to want this to effect all DropDownList's, you might be able to do the following.

```
kendo.ui.DropDownList.fn._change = function(e) {
    if(this.element && this.element.form)
        $(this.element.form).dirtyForms('setDirty');
}
```

This seems kind of hackish and I am not sure if I would recommend doing it though. It might break other things.

Comment: Hi, you are right and this is how I manage to do this but don't you think it's a little ugly to do this on all the DropDownLists ?

Comment: See my edits. It might work for you; but then again I am not sure I would recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like this is a bug that was fixed in [pull request 27](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms/pull/27), which allowed for cross-browser compatibility with select elements.

Or, it could be that you have not [properly ignored all of the 3rd party widgets on the page](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#ignoring-things) that [have anchor elements](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#default-anchor-ignoring-behavior) in their markup.